# How to encrypt text using Bellaso Cipher in python?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, crypt

Does anyone know how to encrypt a message using Bellaso Cipher in python?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the same thing, but here's code for Vigenere's Cipher:

https://github.com/Ahmed-Salama96/vigenere-cipher/blob/master/vigenere.py

Comment: No it's not the same thing. Thanks for your response